# Issue in passing value through delegate

Tags: swift, delegates

i'm trying to pass some value through delegate i think i have done everything for that but my values are isn't passing, i'm confuse that why it isn't passing it. This is where i create my protocol,

```
protocol VideoCallDelegate {
    func videoCallLog(name : String, number: String)
}
var delegate : VideoCallDelegate?

@IBAction func disconnectCallBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    delegate?.videoCallLog(name: channelName!, number: otherUserNumber!)
}
```

and in my destination vc i call it like this,

```
class ContainerCallVC: UIViewController,VideoCallDelegate
func videoCallLog(name: String, number: String) {
    print(name)
    nameArray.append(name)
    numberArray.append(number)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that this

```
var delegate : VideoCallDelegate?
```

is `nil` so when you call this

```
delegate?.videoCallLog(name: channelName, number: otherUserNumber)
```

nothing happens so make sure you set that delegate before you use it to the firstVC , plus if you'll force-unwrap , then it's better to declare it like this from the beginning

```
func videoCallLog(name : String, number: String)
```

**Edit 1:** when you show the secondVC from `ContainerCallVC` , there should be a line like this

```
let secondVc = // 
secondVc.delegate = self
```

regardless of the way you present it push/segue/present

**Edit 2** :

here i suppose call is at tab 2   inside `viewDidLoad` of first tab do

```
let call = self.tabBarController!.viewControllers[1] as! VideoCallVC 
call.delegate = self
```

Comment: i have set the delegate in destination vc but still it isn't getting values. @Sh_Khan

Comment: check it i have eidted. @Sh_Khan

Comment: what comes in sceondVC? @Sh_Khan

Comment: it's the init of the vc that contains **disconnectCallBtnTapped** how do you show it ??

Comment: i have done like this but still value is not going,
let secondVc = VideoCallVC()
        secondVc.delegate = self . @Sh_Khan

Comment: It looks like you're creating a new instance of `VideoCallVC` - please show the code you use to push the view controller.

Comment: i haven't used any push or segue , my destination vc is not connected to this. @Sh_Khan

Comment: is it a child vc inside **ContainerCallVC** ??

Comment: It is two different tabs in tab bar controller. @Sh_Khan